# Eclipse Plugin - Create a view with a table

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I'm currently learning how eclipse plugins work. I want to get a table into a view, and I have been messing with the sample view plugin for a while but I still can't get it to work. Here is the code snippet from the sample view plugin:

```
package com.example.helloworld2.views;


import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.*;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.*;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.ui.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;

public class SampleView extends ViewPart {

    /**
     * The ID of the view as specified by the extension.
     */
    public static final String ID = "com.example.helloworld2.views.SampleView";

    private TableViewer viewer;
    private Action action1;
    private Action action2;
    private Action doubleClickAction;

    /*
     * The content provider class is responsible for
     * providing objects to the view. It can wrap
     * existing objects in adapters or simply return
     * objects as-is. These objects may be sensitive
     * to the current input of the view, or ignore
     * it and always show the same content 
     * (like Task List, for example).
     */

    class ViewContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {
        public void inputChanged(Viewer v, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
        }
        public void dispose() {
        }
        public Object[] getElements(Object parent) {
            return new String[] { "Onsdfsde", "Twosdfsd", "Threesdf" };
        }
    }
    class ViewLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider {
        public String getColumnText(Object obj, int index) {
            return getText(obj);
        }
        public Image getColumnImage(Object obj, int index) {
            return getImage(obj);
        }
        public Image getImage(Object obj) {
            return PlatformUI.getWorkbench().
                    getSharedImages().getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_ELEMENT);
        }
    }
    class NameSorter extends ViewerSorter {
    }

    /**
     * The constructor.
     */
    public SampleView() {
    }

    /**
     * This is a callback that will allow us
     * to create the viewer and initialize it.
     */
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
        viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
        viewer.setSorter(new NameSorter());
        viewer.setInput(getViewSite());

        // Create the help context id for the viewer's control
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(viewer.getControl(), "com.example.helloworld2.viewer");

    }

...
}
```

It seems like the view content provider is responsible for putting content inside the view, but how exactly would I insert a table? Ideally I would eventually like to insert a complex tree table:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/CreateaTreeTable.htm

But if anyone could point me the right direct with something similar or even some resource that I can read up on, that would be wonderful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already inserting a table in createPartControl() as part of "new TableViewer()" call. To insert a different widget you would change createPartControl() to do something different, such as using TreeTableViewer instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Table table = viewer.getTable();`

From what I infer from your question I think that the above code should do what you want.